Git auto created a FILE with git logs inside it
While pushing my commits to the remote branch and after staging files with git add ., Git unexpectedly created a new file named h containing commit logs. I'm unsure why this happened since I hadn't accidentally executed any Git commands, although I did run git log without parameters, which typically doesn't create files.
hfilethatgitadded
I searched online but couldn't find any information related to this issue.

Simple debugging: empty the file, make it read-only (remove write permissions). Watch what process(es) report "Permissions denied". In unix the commands are: >h; chmod a-x h

But this is guaranteed to work only if the process that created the file is still trying to do something to the file right? I highly doubt that's the case @phd

In that case you just remove the file and forget about it. :-)

You probably created that h file unwillingly when viewing git log in your terminal.
If that file got versioned in your latest commit only, simply remove that file from your commit:
git rm h
git commit --amend


By default, git uses a pager to display it's content on a terminal. The default pager is less.
less is a fully fledged program, including a command to write all of its input to a file, which you can trigger by just typing s.
If you saw a log file: line at the bottom, and pressed h [Enter] at that point (perhaps hoping to view the inline help ?) then you created a file named h with the output of git log.
I think I create such files at least once per week :) (named q or N or ... whatever other command I was looking to execute)

Check if there is any Git hooks at .git/hooks using cat .git/hooks/*. They can execute automatically after commit.

I do have some sample hooks that git provides out of the box. None of those are active.

@nandu May you use ProcMon to track which process creates the file? Here is a detailed tutorial.
